# How to verify that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+i^n)(1-n)}{n^2-n+1}=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, proof-verification

> How to verify that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+i^n)(1-n)}{n^2-n+1}=1$

**My Attempt:**
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+i^n)(1-n)}{n^2-n+1}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{-(-n-i^n)(-1+n)}{(n-1)^2}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+i^n}{n-1}$$ Now I just need a tangible argument as to why this converges to $1$. The $i^n$ is really bothering me, any ideas?

Comment: You won't verify that, because the limit is $-1$ ...  BTW $n^2-n+1\neq(n-1)^2$.

Comment: you're right, totally missed that!

Answer (score 3):

Divide numerator and denominator by $n$. Now note (or show) that $\frac{i^n}n\to 0$ (for instance by applying absolute values), and everything's fine.

Comment: Don't I have to elaborate on that? $i^n$ can either be $-1,1,-i,i$?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic They all tend to $0$ if you divide by $n$. Whether you have to elaborate on that is up to whoever is correcting this assignment, and not something I can personally judge.

Comment: True, thanks though!